# Multi Column Block Too Narrow

Tags: css, google-chrome, multiple-columns

Our site dis­plays song lyr­ics in a multi-col­umn for­mat, using CSS. Firefox 22 & MSIE 10+ show the multi-column text correctly, but Chrome (as of version 27.0.1453.116 m) does not. This sample page shows the problem:

**http://www.hymntime.com/tch/test/html5/html5-multicolumn-test.htm**

The page uses a media selector, so your Chrome window must be at least 1280 pixels wide to see the effect. In fact, if you make the Chrome window *less* than 1280 pixels, you'll see the lyrics block change to a **single** column, of the same overall width. But when Chrome shifts from 1-column to 2-column mode (due to the wider browser window), **the lyrics block remains the same width**, causing text to be squeezed together & become unreadable.

Is this a Chrome bug, or are we doing something wrong?